# Problem with the QgsFieldExpressionWidget

Tags: pyqgis-3

I try to customize the QgsFieldExpressionWidget. 
But if I open the Expression Dialog,  the "Fields and Values" are empty.
What I am missing?

```
lay= iface.activeLayer()
wid = QgsFieldExpressionWidget()
wid.setLayer=lay
scope= QgsExpressionContextUtils.layerScope(lay)# QgsExpressionContextScope()
scope.setFields (lay.fields())
wid.appendScope(scope)
wid.registerExpressionContextGenerator (lay)#QgsProject().instance())
wid.expressionDialogTitle="Test"
wid.setExpression('Foto IS NULL')
wid.show()
print (wid.currentText())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**setLayer** is a [method](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFieldExpressionWidget.html#ab4f323c6aa69ac3e47b2a2a46a9d29ea) ,not variable.Change only this for show fields

```
wid.setLayer(lay)
```

Comment: omg, what a stupid mistake. Ok, I am little stressed...
Anyway, thanks a lot, u made my day!